# RxJS Error Observable when another emits value

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs6

Contrived example of what I'm trying to do here:

```
const source = interval(1000);
const errorWhenThisEmits = timer(2500);

source.pipe(/* someOperatorHere? */).subscribe({
  next: () => console.log('next!'),
  error: (err) => console.log(err)
});

// desired outcome:
// 1000ms: next!
// 2000ms: next!
// 2500ms: error message
```

Is it possible to cause the source observable to error when the second observable emits a value?

`takeUntil` gets close, but completes instead of errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could merge the observables

```
const source = interval(1000);
const notifier = timer(2500).pipe(switchMap(() => throwError("error message")));

merge(source, notifier).subscribe({
  next: () => console.log("next!"),
  error: err => console.log(err)
});
```

See stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ony9vx?file=index.ts

Answer (score 1):

Discovered `takeUntil` will error the parent observable if the notifier observable errors.

```
const source = interval(1000);
// added switchMap to throwError
const notifier = timer(2500).pipe(switchMap(() => throwError('error!')));

source.pipe(takeUntil(notifier)).subscribe({
  next: (data) => console.log(data),
  error: (err) => console.log(err)
});
```

This outputs:

```
0
1
error!
```